# Update label from Codebehind in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, xamarin

I'm making an API call to grab items and parse the JSON response. I want to update the screen with the item that's currently being added, however, it's not working.

The code in Xaml file:

```
<Label Text="{DynamicResource status}"/>
```

My codebehind:

```
async void btnLoadItems_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Resources.Add("status", "");

     await LoadItems();

     this.Resources["status"] = "";

     await DisplayAlert("Great", "Your items are loaded.", "OK");
}

foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
     Item item = o.ToObject<Item>();

     this.Resources["status"] = item.name + " being added...";

     items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign a `x:Name` to your `Label` and update it directly

```
<Label x:Name="MyLabel" />
```

if you are updating the UI in a loop you will need to use [MainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread)

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
  MyLabel.Text = item.name + " being added...";
});
```

Comment: It only showed one item in the label for some reason.

Comment: the loop is most likely executing faster than the UI is refreshing

Comment: Ok,that makes sense. Is it possible to use a progress bar control inside of my method to update the percentage relative to the time it takes to execute (even if it's really fast)?

Comment: yes and no.  There is a [ProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/progressbar) but there is no way of knowing in advance how long the operation will take.  You can update the number of iterations vs the total number of nodes you need to process

Comment: So I can put await progressBar.ProgressTo(value, unit, Easing.Linear); inside the loop but what would I use for value and unit?

Comment: I don't think animation will be useful for something that moves this fast - I would just update the Progress property on each loop